# Align post Icon font and Post date properly

Tags: html, css, icons

Here is the image : http://i.imgur.com/E4LYhN2.png. The icon for date and author are not properly aligned with date, author name.

The css code for icon and post date:

```
.entry-meta { /* Container for the entry metadata */
    clear: both;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
// code for icon fonts
.genericon:before {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font: normal 16px 'Genericons';
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.genericon-user:before { content: '\f304'; }
.genericon-month:before{ content: '\f307'; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `vertical-align: top;`

```
vertical-align: middle; /* or try with baseline */
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: Infact it looks best with vertical-align: top, nothing else comes closer.

Comment: @MohitChawla than use `vertical-align: Npx;` + or - or just add `margin-top:2px;` and you're done. Have you seen the link in my answer?